# i have two list of men and girl given height of them for dance competition every boy want smaller girl

Tags: python

i am new to programming so please tell me what to do further with while loop to delete all min values of girl which is < min(men)
or tell me any new way to solve this problem
input will be in form

```
1  # The first line contains T denoting the number of test cases.
4 5 # The first line contains M and N.
2 5 6 8 # line contains M integers each denoting the height of boy
3 8 5 1 7 # line contains N integers each denoting the height of girl.
```

output 'YES'

My existing code:

```
N = int(raw_input())
for i in range(N):
   s = []
   total = raw_input()
   men = list(raw_input())
   girl =list(raw_input())
   s.append(men.sort())
   s.append(girl.sort())
   s.append(total)
   while min(girl) < min(men):
        girl.delete(min(girl))
        men.delete(min(men))
   if len(men) == 0:
        print 'YES'
   else:
        print'NO'
```

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your question? Please explain the problem statement, your expected input (which you have already given), and your expected output. Also, what exactly is the issue with the code you provided? Do you get an error, or is the result incorrect?

Comment: my question is - There would be M boys and N girls at the prom tonight. Each boy wants a girl who is strictly shorter than him. A girl can dance with only one boy and vice-versa. Given the heights of all the boys and girls tell whether it is possible for all boys to get a girl

Comment: for which i get wrong output

Comment: i want to assign the minimum height girl to the minimum height boy if they satisfy the given condition and then remove both the values from their respective list

Comment: Are you reading in the values from a file? Typing them in by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question but from what I see in the comments, I would first order the list from greatest to lowest and then uses  boylist.pop()  and girllist.pop() to delete the last entry in each list (I'm sorry I can't comment that is why this is in the answer format)

Comment: actually i want to ask i want to pop all value of two two list ex li = [1,4,6,8]

Comment: There is probably a simple way to order it backwards but I can only do it in longer ways that I make up if you want me to I can try to make one and append it to my answer

Comment: please see my code i want to ilterate while loop which take min value of list after pop of list every time untill len(men) == 0 in my code it does only 1time

Comment: I don't really get what u r asking me plz be more clear so I can answer and try to include how u changed it

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/tracks/pledge-2015-easy/prom-night/

Comment: please go to this address ..

Comment: I still don't get what u are trying to ask me maybe try a for in loop. If you want a solid foundation in python take free courses from the audacity app particularly intro to computer science

Answer (score 1):

While it's not the prettiest solution, I used a list of dictionary values and ran through two for loops to find girls that are shorter than the current guy:

```
people = [{"Name": "Thomas", 'Gender':'m', 'Height':59},\
{"Name": "James", 'Gender':'m', 'Height':61},\
{"Name": "Jenifer", 'Gender':'f', 'Height':53},\
{"Name": "Audrey", 'Gender':'f', 'Height':62}]

for person in people:
    if person['Gender'].lower() == 'm':
        for female in people:
            if female['Gender'].lower() == 'f':
                if female['Height'] < person['Height']:
                    print "Found",female['Name'],"to date",person['Name']
```

Which outputs:

```
>>>
Found Jenifer to date Thomas
Found Jenifer to date James
```